# Can we perform cryptography on dataset?

Tags: python, encryption, cryptography, dataset

I would like to know if we can perform encryption and decryption techniques i.e., using AES,DES or RSA algorithms on a kaggle dataset?

I have a dataset from kaggle and I would like to encrypt and decrypt that dataset using above algorithms? Is it possible to do so and Can we use jupyter for that?

Comment: As to your question about using Jupyter for that..It's best to think of Jupyter as another development environment. And so usually if you could develop the code in one place without Jupyter, you could also probably use Jupyter.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason why you can't do that. I would use already-built libraries for the encryption algorithms I want to use. Here is one for [AES](https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/cipher/aes.html) for example.